# ¿Cómo puedo importar un proyecto en Genexus Evolution 3?

Tags: genexusxev3

Buen día estimados.

Necesito importar un proyecto en Genexus Evolution 3 alguien que me apoye indicando ¿Cómo lo realizo?.

De antemano Gracias.